# Loading meta data from another page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-load, jquery-attributes

I'm trying to use the [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to grab some meta data from another page and insert it in a `<div>`, but I'm a little stuck.

I'm using something similar on the other page in which I grab the location meta data and put it in a `<p>`. To do this I use the following:

```
<script>
  var locationMeta = $('meta[property="og:locality"]').attr('content');
  $( 'p.locationMeta' ).text( locationMeta );
</script>
```

For this new task, I need to use something like:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "href #target" );
```

The **#target** in this case needs to be **meta[property="og:locality"]**.

*n.b. I've tried to load the p.locationMeta as the target. It loads but it's empty.*

Comment: Assuming `href` is a variable holding the URL to make the request to, you need to concatenate it properly. However, appending `meta` tags dynamically is a little pointless as they are read immediately when the page loads - before any JS runs (that's even assuming JS is executed by the reader).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting load wrong. if you do load(url), url have to be a valid url, a path to the page you're trying to load. you can do load(url selector) like this:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "test.html meta[property='og:locality']" );
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Any idea how I can get the **content** from this?

Comment: if you want to store the content in a variable you could do: content = $( "#mydiv" ).load( "test.html meta[property='og:locality']" ).html();